# GridView paging problem!

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

I enabled paging in my gridview. It pages normally, but when I display 3 items instead of 10, the rows height changes proportionally to suit the gridview height. How can I make the rows be in fixed height! no matter how many items i have on a particular page in Gridview

Comment: Have assigned a fixed value to the `Height` of the `GridView` ??

Comment: The gridview height doesnt change..The rows height does

Comment: Check the value of the `Height` of the `GridView`..

Comment: It is 464px              dafdas

Comment: Try to omit the value of the `Height` of the `GridView` ...

Comment: No, it doesnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify a height for the gridview.

If your rows are larger from columns which have a lot of text, then use maybe something like this around your content:

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 200px; height: 100px;">
    <%# Eval("ColumnName") %>
</div>
```

Better to move into a css class instead of style but that is basically what you need.

Comment: You should use a web inspector that comes with the browser and check what css / styles are applied to the gridview.

Comment: Doesnt the gridview has a property to fix the width of the rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the row height by setting **RowStyle-Height** within the GridView tag itself..
Also you can set the styles of each cell including the header cell by setting attributes in each TemplateField (ItemStyle-Height etc).
see the code below,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    RowStyle-Height="50"  Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Height="50"  HeaderStyle-Height="110" 
            HeaderText="Releases" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                //data binding section
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Whats the #Eval("Release"); does.. and why do i need all that CssClass styles?

Comment: I get this: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Release'.

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, I just used a Grid sample and edited to create a grid structure. So do not mind them all. see only the attributes set. You can find more attributes when you try them..See now i've updated my code.

Comment: I used looked around for colums, header, and pager styles..in the gridView.. and changed their heights and alignments.. it worked!!. Thanks