# asp.net paging changes height

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

title says it all, I have a gridview, and the second page does not fill the 10 places so it changes height, I need the gridview to stay the same no matter what. I will change to whatever I need to get this done, Ive tried everything I can find online like taking out the height attribute and moving it to css, nothing has worked. I also tried all of the answers here and they did not work either...[GridView paging problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555956/gridview-paging-problem)

the CSS i tried is:

```
.RowStyle {
 height: 50px;
 }
 .AlternateRowStyle {
  height: 50px;
 }
```

and the HTML I am using currently is:

```
<asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="AnonymousMessagePanel">
         <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="CompletedProjectsGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ProjectsClosedList" 
            EnableViewState="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  RowStyle-CssClass="RowStyle" 
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="ProjectID" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="ProjectID" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="ProjectName" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="ProjectName" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TesterName" HeaderText="TesterName" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="TesterName" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectDescription" HeaderText="ProjectDescription" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="ProjectDescription" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Platform" HeaderText="Platform" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="Platform" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="DueDate" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="DueDate" dataformatstring="{0:M/dd/yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAssigned" HeaderText="DateAssigned" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="DateAssigned" dataformatstring="{0:M/dd/yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentName" HeaderText="DocumentName" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="DocumentName" ItemStyle-Width="11%"/>
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProjectsClosedList" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectsAndTasksTestConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], [ProjectName], [TesterName], [ProjectDescription], [Platform], [DueDate], [DateAssigned], [DocumentName] FROM [Projects] WHERE ([DateCompleted] IS NULL)">
               </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Note: all of these ways do actually run and work, they just all change height of the gridview when there is only 2/10 on the last page, and I need it the same height no matter what is in the page

If this is not the best way to achieve this, I am open to better options

Comment: Do I need to set the position to absolute of something?

Answer (score 0):

use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
.RowStyle,.AlternateRowStyle{
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

or just

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

you can have a look at [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) too

Comment: hmm....that didnt work either...I must have a word wrong somewhere or something I don't get why it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your `RowStyle-CssClass="RowStyle` and do this and see if it works:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="ProjectID" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="ProjectID" ReadOnly="True">
 <ItemStyle CssClass="RowStyle"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

Somehow I feel some of your other styles are influencing the height.

Or try following:

```
.RowStyle 
{
     height: 50px !important;
}
.AlternateRowStyle 
{
      height: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried getting rid of them and moving them. I tried this and it breaks my gridview.

Comment: @Geraldvance by break do you mean the style breaks or something else?

Comment: oh, sorry, I should have known that would conflict, it gives me an error and the gridview will no longer show on my page                                                            EDIT actually it does work i had it written wrong, the rows change but when i go to page 2 it still changes the height base on the 2/10 that remain

Comment: still the same problem, I tried it with and without the <itemstyle> portions as well

Comment: keep your code same , just as before , just change the css and see.

Comment: Ok, yeah same thing then